# phpunit - how to populate database with geometry type

Tags: geometry, phpunit

As in topic.
How to init database testcase with geometry type?
If as a source I give:
`array('id' => 1, 'point' => 'GeomFromText(\'POINT(1 1)\')'),`
it generates error: `Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field]`

I'm using those classes: `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_AbstractDataSet`, `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTableMetaData`, `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultTable`

Answer (score 1):

DbUnit does not support MySQL's geometry types.